# Hangfire + SimpleInjector + MVC

Tags: c#, hangfire

I’m trying to setup Hangfire for our MVC app. I followed all tutorials, used Devmondo HangFire.SimpleInjector for activator logic but still have issues.

My startup setup is as following:

```
//Hangfire
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(webClientConfigurationService.DataConnectionStringName);
Hangfire.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseActivator(new SimpleInjectorJobActivator(Core.Dependencies.DependencyResolver.Container));
app.UseHangfireDashboard();
app.UseHangfireServer();

        //add hangfire test job
        var _selfAccreditationsService = Core.Dependencies.DependencyResolver.Resolve<ISelfAccreditationsService>();
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => _selfAccreditationsService.TestHangFire(), Cron.MinuteInterval(1));
```

Application starts fine but when I go to dasboard I can see:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type ‘SimpleInjector.Lifestyles.AsyncScopedLifestyle’ from assembly ‘SimpleInjector, Version=3.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=984cb50dea722e99’.
at Hangfire.SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorJobActivator.BeginScope(JobActivatorContext context)
at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0()
at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.InvokePerformFilter(IServerFilter filter, PerformingContext preContext, Func1 continuation) at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.PerformJobWithFilters(PerformContext context, IEnumerable1 filters)
at Hangfire.Server.BackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
at Hangfire.Server.Worker.PerformJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String jobId)
```

EDIT: Even with fresh MVC template project after adding all of above it’s still giving me same error :frowning:

Do you guys have any ideas what I have missed? Would really appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Tomasz, Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Hello @dalcam, It turned out to be that one of DLL that my application loaded was not the version expected I was able to find out what was wrong and resolve using Visual Studio Modules window. It had nothing to do with Hangfire at the end.